# I am designing a bus timetable using SQL. Each bus route has multiple stops, do I need a different table for each route?

Tags: sql, bus, timetable

I am trying to come up with the most efficient database as possible. My bus routes all have about 10 stops. The bus starts at number one until it reaches the 10th stop, then it comes back again. This cycle happens 3 times a day.

I am really stuck as to how I can efficiently generate the times for the buses and where I should store the stops. If I put all the stops in one field and the times in another, the database won't be very dynamic.

If I store all the stops one by one in a column and then the times in another column, there will be a lot of repeating happening further down as one stop has multiple times.

Maybe I am missing something, I've only just started learning SQL and this is a task we have been set.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the stops designated? Do they have unique numbers or names?

Comment: They all have 10 stops? Goes round the loop 3x daily? The same for all routes? Sounds like a rather complicated homework question...

Comment: Certainly possible, real bus scheduling is never this simple or straightforward...

Comment: They all have roughly 10 stops, they are unique names. It is very complicated :(, we are only allowed to use Terminal and PostgresSQL to make it as well, no GUIs' :(

It doesn't have to be super realistic, we just need to show we can solve the problem in an efficient way.

Thanks for taking the time to comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need one table that contains your `Timetable`:

- Route ID
- Stop ID
- Time
- Possibly other fields as needed (direction, sequence #'s, Block #, etc)

I would recommend creating separate tables `Bus Stop` (to store stop names, lat/longs, etc) and `Route` (to store route name, first stop, last stop, direction, etc).

You are probably aware of this already, but bus scheduling can get complicated very quickly. For example:

- You may need to designate certain stops as "Time Points" which show up in the printed schedules
- Each route may have multiple variations. For example, some versions may start or end at a different bus stop
- The schedule will probably be different on Saturday and Sunday, and most agencies change their schedules quarterly

You may need to consider some of these cases, and build them into your schema.

Does that help?

Comment: Hey thanks, that is very helpful. At the moment I have a different table for different coloured routes, they are all linked to a 'main' table via foreign keys. 

I was thinking I could store the time it look to get to each stop, then use the php time functions to calculate the time as the loop generates my time table.

Hopefully I am going in the right direction.

Is it possible to set a field to have a default value? For example, each stop name under the table blue_route, has a field which gets the text 'blue' automatically assigned to it, like an incrementing field. Hope that makes sense :S

Comment: I recommend just using one table for all routes, but other than that your approach is sound. You can use the DEFAULT keyword to set default table values, just check the docs for the Database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Here's just one (of the many) ways to do this:

It sounds like you probably want to have a `routes` table, which describes each route, and has a start time.

Then, a `stops` table with descriptions and wait times for the bus at each stop.

A `stopDistanceMapping` table would describe the distance between two stops, and the drive time between them.

Finally, your `routeMap` table will link individual `routes` with a list of `stops`. You can then fill your `routes` table distance and time in using the wait time from each individual stop, and the times/distances from `stopDistanceMapping`.

Good luck!

Comment: This would be a much more efficient way of doing it, I am just not sure how I can link the stops to the different routes. So for example if I wanted to select all stops belonging to route blue. That would be ok, but what if some stops belonged to multiple routes :S

Been doing this database stuff a week now and it's pretty hardcore, i'm liking it though :)

Answer (score 0):

On a (very rough) 1st pass,   I would keep the bus route times in a table like this:

```
RouteID StartingLocationID  EndingLocationID TravelTime
```

Also I would keep a table of stops such as:

```
StopID Address City etc... (whatever other information you need about each location)
```

For the routes themselves I would store:

```
RouteID StartingLocationID RouteStartTime
```

Obviously you should tailor this to your own needs, but this should give you a place to start.

Comment: Hey, thanks, this is something I had thought of, but with the stops in a seporate table, how can I show which stop belongs to different routes? Especially if one stop belongs to multiple routes

Comment: Sorry I guess I wasn't clear.... The StartingLocationID/EndingLocationID should correspond to an entry in the Stops table.   Looking at the combination of RouteID and (StartingID OR EndingID) should provide an accurate map of each bus's route.